# Heading numbering without messing the text

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to number the headings which divide a text in Word 2013.

As recommended by Microsoft (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-your-headings-ce24e028-4cb4-4d4a-bf25-fb2c61fc6585)), I'm numbering  headings by multilevel lists.

However, whenever I try to include a heading in a list, the text below is also incorporated. This messes its formatting up. Fixing this manually is burdensome and often breaks the list up, causing further numbering attempts to start new lists instead.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot that demonstrates the problem? Also, check that you're using paragraph breaks after your headings and not line breaks (hitting the `ENTER` key, not `SHIFT`+`ENTER`).

Comment: May be, you are not using heading multilevel list, but only regular multilevel list - please double check.